# Laziness in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, d, lazy-evaluation

Do you know how to perform a lazy evaluation of string, like in this D snippet:

```
void log(lazy string msg) {
  static if (fooBarCondition)
    writefln(…) /* something with msg */
}
```

Actually, the problem might not need laziness at all since the *static* if. Maybe it’s possible to discard `char const*` strings when not used? Like, in C++:

```
void log(char const *msg) {
  #ifdef DEBUG
  cout << … << endl; /* something with msg */
  #else /* nothing at all */
  #endif
}
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: The best way to do stuff like this IMO is macros, to avoid building the message to be passed if not needed.  (see the `assert` macro)

Comment: The use of `static if` looks inviting

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, it’ a `D` metaprograming feature

Comment: @skp I know. It's still inviting.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: It has been proposed to the C++ standard committee, I am not sure it will fly by due to some of the deeper implications. The current C++ allows a similar thing through `#ifdef`, but the ifdef is evaluated at preprocessing time while `static if` is a compile time evaluation (i.e. can use templates, constants --not just other defines--...

Comment: @skp: You need to be clearer as of what you really need. Why is the macro approach not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: it is, I just couldn’t mark it as answer yet. Now it’s done :)

Comment: "Actually, the problem might not need laziness at all since the static if." -- You don't appear to understand what that `lazy` does in D ... it means that, if the static_if is false, the calling expression doesn't have to be calculated. In C++11 you can get the same effect (but not as cleanly) by taking a lambda expression as an argument.

Comment: I know what `lazy` does, that’s why I asked how to do that in C++. macros are what I need ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define log(msg) do { cout << … << endl; } while(0)
#else
#define log(msg) do { } while(0)
#endif
```

There are two ways to achieve laziness in C++11: macros and lambda expressions. Both are not "lazy" technically, but what is called "normal evaluation" (as opposed to "eager evaluation"), which mean that an expression might be evaluated any number of times.  So if you are translating a program from D (or haskell) to C++ you will have to be careful not to use expressions with side effects (including computation time) in these expressions.

To achieve true laziness, you will have to implement memoizing, which is not that simple.

For simple logging, macros are just fine.

Comment: that's the way to get "lazy evaluation", unless you want to mess with lambdas. I don't think you want to do that for logging.

Answer (score 3):

You could mix macros and lambdas to create this effect

you could have a type, lazy

```
template<class T>
class lazy {
    ...
}
```

and then you could have a LAZY wrapper that created one of these using a lambda

```
#define LAZY(E) my_lazy_type<decltype((E))>([&](){ return E; })
```

All my_lazy_type needs is a constructor that accepts a std::function, and a an overload of operator() that evaluates and returns this. On each evaluation you can replace the thunk with a thunk that just returns the already computed value and thus it would only get computed once.

edit:
here is an example of what I am talking about. I would like however to point out that this is not a perfect example. it passes around a bunch of stuff by value in side the lazy which may completely defeat the purpose of doing this all in the first place. It uses mutable inside this because I need to be able to memoize the thunk in const cases. This could be improved in a lot of ways but it's a decent proof of concept.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#define LAZY(E) lazy<decltype((E))>{[&](){ return E; }}

template<class T>
class lazy {
private:
    struct wrapper {
        std::function<T()> thunk;
        wrapper(std::function<T()>&& x)
            : thunk(std::move(x)) {}
        wrapper(const std::function<T()>& x)
            : thunk(x) {}
    };
    //anytime I see mutable, I fill a bit odd
    //this seems to be warented here however
    mutable std::shared_ptr<wrapper> thunk_ptr;
public:
    lazy(std::function<T()>&& x)
        : thunk_ptr(std::make_shared<wrapper>(std::move(x))) {}
    T operator()() const {
        T val = thunk_ptr->thunk();
        thunk_ptr->thunk = [val](){return val;};
        return val;
    }
};

void log(const lazy<std::string>& msg) {
    std::cout << msg() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::string hello = "hello";
    std::string world = "world";
    log(LAZY(hello + ", " + world + "!"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but for logging stuff it’s quite overkill, don’t you think?

Comment: Sure it's overkill, I was answering the question of how to achieve laziness. If you're goal is just logging, I don't really see why you need laziness at all.

Comment: @Jake Why `wrapper` is needed? Couldn't there be just be `std::shared_ptr` to `std::function<T()>` ??

Comment: I have completely forgotten what I was thinking then truth be told. Looking at it now it looks silly. I wrote another version here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701108/a-way-of-achieving-lazy-evaluation-in-c?lq=1 and it seems I took it out in that version. I can't remember what I was thinking. It looks like an artifact of my design process that I didn't take out until later.

Answer (score 0):

While Elazar's answer works, I prefer not to use macros for this (especially not ones with all-lowercase names).
Here is what I would do instead:

```
template<bool /* = false */>
struct logger_impl {

    template<typename T>
    static std::ostream & write(std::ostream & stream, T const &) {
        return stream;
    }
};

template<>
struct logger_impl<true> {

    template<typename T>
    static std::ostream & write(std::ostream & stream, T const & obj) {
        return stream << obj;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void log(T const & obj) {
#if defined(NDEBUG)
    logger_impl<true>::write(std::cout, obj);
#else
    logger_impl<false>::write(std::cout, obj);
#endif
}
```

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: This IfThenElse template is quite useful, but it is *not* lazy. The expression inside `log(exp)` *will* be evaluated each time, even when `NDEBUG` is not defined.