# memory management for lambda in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Could someone describe why this code doesn't work (on GCC4.7.3 seg-faults before returning from call)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template<typename F>
auto memo(const F &x) -> std::function<decltype(x())()> {
    typedef decltype(x()) return_type;
    typedef std::function<return_type()> thunk_type;
    std::shared_ptr<thunk_type> thunk_ptr = std::make_shared<thunk_type>();

    *thunk_ptr = [thunk_ptr, &x]() {
        cerr << "First " << thunk_ptr.get() << endl;
        auto val = x();
        *thunk_ptr = [val]() { return val; };
        return (*thunk_ptr)();
    };

    return [thunk_ptr]() { return (*thunk_ptr)(); };
};

int foo() {
    cerr << "Hi" << endl;
    return 42;
}

int main() {
    auto x = memo(foo);
    cout << x() << endl ;
    cout << x() << endl ;
    cout << x() << endl ;
};
```

My original assumptions:

1. each `std::function<T()>` is kinda reference/shared_ptr to some object that represents closure. I.e. life-time of picked up value is limited by it.
2. `std::function<T()>` object have assignment operator that will abandon old closure (end life-time picked values) and will take ownership for a new value.

P.S. This question raised after I read [question about lazy in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16701108/230744)

Comment: Hm, somehow `thunk_ptr` ends up owning itself. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @KerrekSB, yes, agree, but this should get memory-leak rather than seg-fault

Comment: The reason behind `return (*thunk_ptr)();` is to return reference to field of closure `[val]() { return val; }` if references added to `thunk_type`. See (alternative implementation of `lazy` in my answer)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/19125422/230744]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problematic code:

```
[thunk_ptr, &x]() {
    auto val = x();
    *thunk_ptr = [val]() { return val; };
    return (*thunk_ptr)(); // <--- references a non-existant local variable
}
```

The problem is that the local `thunk_ptr` is a copy from the context. That is, in the assignment `*thunk_ptr = ...` the `thunk_ptr` refers to the copy owned by the function object. However, with the assignment the function object ceases to exist. That is, on the next line `thunk_ptr` refers to a just destroyed object.

There are a few approaches to fix the problem:

1. Instead of getting fancy, just return `val`. The problem here is that `return_type` may be a reference type which would cause this approach to fail.
2. Return the result straight from the assignment: prior to the assignment `thunk_ptr` is still alive and after the assignment it still return a reference to the `std::function<...>()` object:

   ```
   return (*thunk_ptr = [val](){ return val; })();
   ```
3. Safe a copy of `thunk_ptr` and use this copy to call the function object in the `return` statement:

   ```
   std::shared_ptr<thunk_type> tmp = thunk_ptr;
   *tmp = [val]() { return val; };
   return (*tmp)();
   ```
4. Save a copy of reference to `std::function` and use it instead of referring to field that belongs to overwritten closure:

   ```
   auto &thunk = *thunk_ptr;
   thunk = [val]() { return val; };
   return thunk();
   ```

Comment: The whole idea is to have lazy calculation of `val`. That's why there is two "continuations" (evaluation and returning evaluated value). Please note as well that I allocate `std::function<T()>` on heap with `std::make_shared` and later I copy one shared-ptr to first closure (increment ref) and later I copy that shared-ptr again in second closure (in total +2 refs) and after exit from function I drop one ref. In total 2 refs: one held by first closure (circular ref as @KerrekSB mentioned) and one held by returning closure (might be freed and dropped down to 1 ref). I can't see what you say.

Comment: @ony: The issue is **not** with the `std::function<...>` object but with the local copy of the `std::shared_ptr<...>` within the replacing lambda: the `std::finction<...>` object is the only owner of this lambda. When you assign to the `std::function<...>` object the lambda us destroyed and with it the `std::shared_ptr<...>` (`thunk_ptr`). You need to keep a copy of `thunk_ptr` when you want to access the `std::function<...>` object as `thunk_ptr` gets destroyed (the assignment to the `std::function<...>` behaves like `delete this`). ... and I understand the intention of what this does!

Comment: Yes, you are right `thunk_ptr` inside closure refers to address of field inside closure object that was destroyed by that assignment with new closure. Sorry, I misinterpreted your answer. I'll wait when SO will let me vote here again. Could you edit your answer just to let me undo my downvote.

Comment: I've added another 4th variant (tiny modification of 3rd) and got a chance to undo my downvote.

Comment: In addition to all of that, the lambda include a by-reference capture `&x`, such a lambda cannot be used after the defining function returns.